# Hackerrank TestCases are incorrect? Dijkstra Shortest Reach 2

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

**Hackerrank - Dijkstra Shortest Reach 2**

I got stuck at TestCase 7 (the only one I failed) which I thought was my fault. I downloaded the test case and checked against my output generated.

I do git diff and I can't see any difference between them. Can you help me verify what happened to my code?

Or perhaps if there isn't a catch in my code, I would like to alter the question:

**Does HackerRank Platform often has bugs?**

I often encountered an obscure failure (usually last one or two out of 13 testcases) when doing a HackerRank Challenge for my job interview, hence failed multiple times at these. I wonder if any of you has similar experience. My suspicion is that when I checked my submitted code with friends, we can't find any edge cases or bugs. It should be perfect. As programmer who had been coding in LeetCode, this terrifies me and I started to train on HackerRank.

Please advise. Thanks

Resource:

- Hackerrank Problems: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dijkstrashortreach/problem
- Input and Output for TestCase7: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/13Qa0k1mIZ5hVW32bRQa15_s8rH7f0-v4

P.S in the google drive folder, I attached my output: `output_me.txt` and the ground truth output: `output.txt`. I did add new lines for both output (initially, all answer are in one long line, added new lines to make it easier to read.)

Code:

```py
import os
from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import heappop, heappush

MAX_INT = 2**31


# Build Graph
def buildGraph(edges):
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    trackMinEdge = {}

    # build min edges from u - v (adjacent)
    # for handling duplicate edges
    for u, v, weight in edges:
        u, v = min(u, v), max(u, v)
        if (u, v) in trackMinEdge:
            minWeight = trackMinEdge[(u, v)]
            if minWeight <= weight:
                # do not update
                continue
        # only update if (u, v) not in trackMinWeight
        # or the new weight is smaller than minWeight
        trackMinEdge[(u, v)] = weight

    # build graph from minimum adjancent edge
    for u, v in trackMinEdge:
        weight = trackMinEdge[(u, v)]
        graph[u].append((weight, v))
        graph[v].append((weight, u))

    return graph

# DJIKSTRA
def djikstra(n, graph, src, dest=None):
    dists = {}

    # setups
    seen = set()
    queue = [(0, src)]
    dists[src] = 0
    while queue:
        dist_u, u = heappop(queue)
        if u in seen: continue

        seen.add(u)
        for weight, v in graph.get(u, []):
            if v in seen: continue

            alt = dists[u] + weight
            if alt < dists.get(v, MAX_INT):
                dists[v] = alt
                heappush(queue, (alt, v))

    return dists


# Complete the shortestReach function below.
def shortestReach(n, edges, src):
    graph = buildGraph(edges)

    # edge cases: src not connected to any node
    if not (src in graph):
        return [-1 for _ in range(n-1)] 

    dists = djikstra(n, graph, src)

    distsTable = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i in dists and i != src:
            distsTable.append(dists[i])
        elif not (i in dists):
            distsTable.append(-1)

    return distsTable


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w+')

    t = int(input())

    for t_itr in range(t):
        nm = input().split()

        n = int(nm[0])

        m = int(nm[1])

        edges = []

        for _ in range(m):
            edges.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

        s = int(input())

        result = shortestReach(n, edges, s)

        fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
        fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Regards,

Me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it actually works correctly for **Test Case#7** on **PyCharm** - actual output matches the one in the expected output. However the same code is failing on **Hackerrank** due to **Runtime Error**. Why can it happen?

According to [Hackerrank FAQ](https://www.hackerrank.com/faq)

> Runtime error/Segmentation Fault. Your code terminated unexpectedly.
>   Did you overrun your array? Is your code trying to divide by zero?

Obviously, it's not because we divide something by `0` since it works locally. What else? According to [Hackerrank Environment](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment) for **Python** there's a memory limit of `512 Mb` for solutions.

So, I decided to measure the memory usage for your solution using `tracemalloc` module.

```
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()
...
# <solution code here>
...
print("Current usage: %d, Peak usage: %d" % tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
```

**Output**

> Current usage: 549627153, Peak usage: 550966939

As you can see, it's actually above the limit of `512 Mb` and that's why you can have this `Runtime Error`. Hence, try to reduce the space complexity for your solution.

I also noticed another problem - if you measure your time complexity using the `time` module then it takes more than `40` seconds for **Test Case#7** to complete. So, it can be your next issue if you fix the space complexity issue first.

And finally, no, there's no bug on **Hackerrank** here - my **Python** solution has passed all the tests.

**UPDATE**

As asked by @Daniel (author of the question) I'm providing my optimised version of the solution that passes all the tests on **Hackerrank**.

```
# Complete the shortestReach function below.
def shortestReach(n, distanceMatrix, s):
    queue = list()
    queue.append(s)

    minDistances = [-1] * (n + 1)
    minDistances[s] = 0

    while queue:
        currentNode = queue.pop(0)

        for neighbor in distanceMatrix[currentNode]:
            newDistance = minDistances[currentNode] + distanceMatrix[currentNode][neighbor]
            prevDistance = minDistances[neighbor]
            if minDistances[neighbor] == -1:
                minDistances[neighbor] = newDistance
            else:
                minDistances[neighbor] = min(newDistance, minDistances[neighbor]) 

            if prevDistance != minDistances[neighbor]:
                queue.append(neighbor)      

    del minDistances[s]
    del minDistances[0]
    print (' '.join(map(str, minDistances)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = int(input())

    for t_itr in range(t):
        nm = input().split()

        n = int(nm[0])

        m = int(nm[1])

        distanceMatrix = [dict() for _ in range(n + 1)]
        for _ in range(m):
            edge = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
            i = edge[0]
            j = edge[1]
            weight = edge[2]
            if i not in distanceMatrix[j]:
                distanceMatrix[i][j] = distanceMatrix[j][i] = weight    
            else:
                distanceMatrix[i][j] = distanceMatrix[j][i] = min(weight, distanceMatrix[i][j])

        s = int(input())

        shortestReach(n, distanceMatrix, s)
```

There's no reason for using a `heap` here - `queue` is completely enough. The only criterium of adding a node to `queue` is if its distance has changed at the current step.